# how to display http error message angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular6

I am using the below methods to send data. I want to display an error response on my component. How can I console log error message in my component?

**component.ts**

```
signup(){ 
    return this.loginservice.signupUser(this.model).subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data.error);
    });
}
```

**service ts**

```
signupUser(signupuserModel: any = {}):Observable<any>{
    return this.http.post(`${this.signuouserurl}`,signupuserModel)
}
```

**error message**
[image]

Comment: What is the output of `console.log(data.error);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In RxJS, `subscribe()` method can have 3 functions

1. `next()` if observable emits value.
2. `error()` if there's an error thrown from the Observable
3. `complete()` if the observable is completed.

What you need to do is to add an extra arrow function in your server call inside `subscribe()` method

```
public error: any; 

signup() { 
    return this.loginservice.signupUser(this.model).subscribe(success => {
        console.log(success);
    }, error => { // second parameter is to listen for error
        console.log(error);
        this.error = error;
    });
}
```

If you want to show the error in your component.html, you can use the interpolation {{ }}

**component.html**

```
<div class="error">{{ error }}</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
signup() { 
  return this.loginservice.signupUser(this.model).subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data);
  }, err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
}
```

You can also use try-catch approach in following way

```
async signup() { 
  try {
    let data = await this.loginservice.signupUser(this.model).toPromise();
    console.log(data)
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}
```

However not all http codes raise exception

Answer (score 1):

you can choose any method to display an error.. on of the best way is seprate the success and error response with following code (for this your http call must thrown an exception if not then you have to chose the second option )

```
signup() { 
  return this.loginservice.signupUser(this.model).subscribe(success => {
    console.log(success);
  }, error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
}
```

or you can write conditional code like

```
    signup() { 
          return this.loginservice.signupUser(this.model).subscribe(success => {
            console.log(data);
    if(success.status == 406){ console.log("success")} 
else { console.log("Error ") }
          }
        }
```